# NodeJS Hash function

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, md5, bcrypt

I have NodeJs app with MongoDb and I have there unique MAC addresses. I want to hash this addresses somehow, because I feel that storing raw MAC addresses is not the best option. I need some quite fast hashing function where `hash(address) = same_output_everytime`, because the hash be use also for identification. I don't want to use bcrypt because I think it is too overpowered for this purpose and not so fast. I'm thinking about MD5. What do you think is the best hash for this purpose?

Comment: Hashing can't be "too overpowered" also "not so fast" doesn't matter, we are talking about nanoseconds here.

Comment: so what hash do you think is the best for this purpose? I tried bcrypt but the output is sometimes different for same inputs.

Comment: https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/choosing-right-hashing-algorithm-slowness

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/choosing-right-hashing-algorithm-slowness I decided to use scrypt.